# List VS Code recent workspaces from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Opening up a new instance of VS Code and then pressing `ctrl`+`R` shows a list of nearly all of the Workspaces that have been recently been opened.

How can I get this list from the command line?

Are they stored in a json or text file?

Comment: On a Windows system, it looks like they are all buried in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\<uniqueHashCode>\workspace.json`. The path is the `"folder":` item in that json.

Comment: Does anyone know where this file belongs on macOS?

Comment: @HenryBlyth `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage` I'd like to be able to list the open workspaces from the command line so that I can open a file from the command line and guarantee that it opens in the appropriate workspace (i.e. open a workspace first if one doesn't already exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Windows 10 system, the following powershell script returns the paths for each saved VS Code workspace file sorted in order of last accessed.  Change the `$WorkSpacesPath` path variable accordingly.

**EDIT** to reflect recent changes to vscode core and how it saves references to workspace files.  Probably a better way to do this, but this will suffice.

```proto
$WorkSpacesPath = "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage"

$ws =  (
    Get-Item -Path $WorkSpacesPath\*\*.json | `
    Foreach-Object  { 
        (Get-Content ($_.FullName) | ConvertFrom-Json).configuration `
        -Replace 'file:///|[\s]+', '' `
        -Replace '/', '\' `
        -Replace '%3a', ':' `
        -Replace '%20', ' ' `
        }
    )

## BEGIN EDIT
$ws +=  (
    (Get-Item -Path $CodeWorkSpaces\*\*.json | `
    Foreach-Object  { 
        (Get-Content ($_.FullName) | ConvertFrom-Json).configuration.fsPath `
        }
    ) | `
    Where-Object { $_ } | `
    Get-Unique -AsString | `
    Foreach-Object {
        Get-Item -Path $_ -EA SilentlyContinue | `
        Select-Object -Property BaseName, FullName, LastAccessTime  `
    } | `
    Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime `
) 
## END EDIT

 $ws | `
    Where-Object { $_ } | `
    Get-Unique -AsString | `
    Foreach-Object {
        Get-Item -Path $_ -EA SilentlyContinue | `
        Select-Object -Property BaseName, FullName, LastAccessTime  `
    } | `
    Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime 

$idx = 0
$ws | Foreach-Object {$_ | Add-Member @{Index = $idx } -Force; $idx++ } 

$ws | Select-Object -Property Index, BaseName, LastAccessTime, FullName
```